# How I can format this line into formatted code using regex

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

How I can convert this line :

```
        <user_profil><username>root</username><email>root@foo.bar</email></user_profil>
```

into something formatted like :

```
<user_profil>
    <username>root</username>
    <email>root@foo.bar</email>
</user_profil>
```

using regex.

Also I dont understand why `$doc->saveHTML()` *(an instance of DOMDocument)* return the result as one line only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually using regex would be the longer option. Rather use

```
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

This should get you the formatted code.

Answer (score 5):

Using @georoot way is better, but if you want to try regex, you can do it this way:

```
(\s+)(\<\w+\>)(\<\w+\>\w+\<\/\w+\>)(\<\w+\>[\w\@\.]+\<\/\w+\>)(\<\/\w+\>)
```

Replace with:

```
$2\n\t$3\n\t$4\n$5
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QtVCoY/1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.